# Python: Import module outside current folder with specific path configuration

Tags: python, python-import

I have a folder structure like this

```
root
|-config
  |-config.ini
|-src
  |-A
    |-file1
  |-file2
```

Now file2 gets initialization information from config.ini, so it contains the following code:

```
# file2.py
def __init__(self, ...)
...
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read_file(open("../config/config.ini"))
...
```

and the test main in file2 works perfectly

file2 is used also from file1, it imports it using the instruction:

```
# file1.py
from src.file2 import MyModule
```

BUT when it tries to initialize a file2's object,

```
def __init__(self, ...):
  m = MyModule()
...
```

it does not find the config.ini path.
Of course it works if I change the path in file2 to the following

```
    config.read_file(open("../../config/config.ini"))
```

Is there a simple and pythonic way to set the path so that it works on the local file2 main and file1 main?

Comment: Use absolute path for accessing the files/folders or else if you want to access it relative to the file then `os.path.join([os.path.dirname(__file__), .., config, config.ini])`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, clear! just "why" did you use a list? it gives an error, it works without.

Comment: My mistake it doesn't use any list it just take comma separated path so it can create correct path according to the OS. Just a habit to wrap comma separated as list. Sry.